# Android Cannot create new folder

Tags: android

I cannot create new folder any way, it always return false when use mkdirs. I am using Android 6.0.1 in android studio debug mode.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" android:maxSdkVersion="18" />`

String folder_main = "NewFolder";
        Boolean success = false;
        File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),folder_main
                );
        if (!f.exists()) {
            Log.d("path","not exist");
            success=f.mkdirs();
        }
        else
        {
            Log.d("path","exist");
        }

        Log.d("path",success.toString());
```

I didn't use write permission since in this [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)

> Starting in API level 19, this permission is not required to
>   read/write files in your application-specific directories returned by
>   getExternalFilesDir(String) and getExternalCacheDir().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The doc says you can read/write files only in the directories returned by getExternalFilesDir(String) and getExternalCacheDir() without write permission. But you get directory path by Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().

[Javadoc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageDirectory()) of Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() says.

> Writing to this path requires the WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission, and starting in KITKAT, read access requires the READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission, which is automatically granted if you hold the write permission.
>
> Starting in KITKAT, if your application only needs to store internal data, consider using getExternalFilesDir(String), getExternalCacheDir(), or getExternalMediaDirs(), which require no permissions to read or write.